# how to go to application's stack in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an applicaton, which need a pop up to be shown from a service for which I have started an activity with flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. It has two buttons A and B. After clik of both buttons I am finishing the activity.

But even after I finish this activity (pop up), when I select my activity from recent activities (If i long press home button), I am directed to the pop up activity. How do I go my application's main stack?